# test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider - SSIS

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, windows-server-2003-r2

Below is my machine information:

Windows Server 2003, service pack 2, 32 bit.
SSIS package is developed on SQL server 2005.
Connection string : Data Source=Source;User ID=xxx;Provider=MSDAORA.1;Persist Security Info=True

When I'm trying to connect Oracle DB its showing error (test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider).How can I know, which Oracle client I need to install for this. I checked here (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0819acf0-f53e-402a-8113-e8d87f8def5b/test-connection-failed-because-of-an-error-in-initializing-provider-oracle-client-and-networking?forum=sqlintegrationservices). But the answer seems to be for a different versions. How to know, what to install and from where to install ? Please suggest proper link. I hope I have explained it correctly.

Screenshot attached
[image]

The server registry shows like this:

[image]

Comment: Reading that message is it more to do with the account your using being locked? so access is denied for that reason? Unlock the account and try the test connection again